# Obtener M primeras filas de una matriz con NumPy

Tags: python, numpy

Si tengo una matriz numPy tal que:

[
 [0,2.2]
 [1,3.4]
 [...,...]
 [...,...]
 [N,xxx.xxx]
]

Siendo N la cantidad de filas, y siempre teniendo 2 columnas. Quiero obtener una submatriz de las M primeras filas.
¿Alguna forma de hacerlo con numPy?

## Edit 1:

No quiero iterar a lo loco ya que pierdo eficiencia final en el algoritmo, y estoy en la fase de optimizarlo, pero no encuentro en la documentación de numpy algo que me funcione. Probé con lo siguiente:

```
_cantidad               = np.arange(cantidad)
defSubMatrix            = np.ix_(_cantidad,[0,1])
matrizCorrelPos         = matrizCorrelPos[defSubMatrix]
```

Pero no me generaba los resultados esperados cuando la cantidad != matriz.shape[0].size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No sé si estoy entendiendo bien la pregunta, porque si es lo que estoy entendiendo, se trata simplemente de poner:

```
matriz[:N, :]
```

lo cual no es más que es un caso bastante estándar del uso de *slices* para seleccionar rangos de elementos contiguos en numpy.

En general, para una matriz de dos dimensiones, la forma de seleccionar una sub-matriz es:

```
matriz[slice1, slice2]
```

Siendo `slice1` el rango de filas deseadas, y `slice2` el de columnas. Estos *slices* siguen la sintaxis estándar python:

```
inicio:fin:paso
```

En el que si se omite `inicio` se considera 0 y si se omite `fin` se considera "hasta el último elemento inclusive`. El`paso`permite elegir filas/columnas de n en n. Si se omite`:paso`se considera`:1`, pero si se usa por ejemplo`:2`serviría por ejemplo para extraer las filas pares (si`inicio`es 0) o impares (si`inicio`es 1). Finalmente, si se usa`paso`=-1 se pueden recorrer en orden inverso.

En nuestro caso, el primer *slice* es  `:N`, que equivale a `0:N:1`, es decir,  las N primeras filas contiguas, mientras que el segundo *slice* es `:`, que equivale a `0::1`, es decir "todas las columnas", contiguas y en orden.

### Nota

La solución que propones en tu respuesta, usando `np.arange(N)` produce el mismo resultado pero es más ineficiente por dos razones:

- El uso de `arange(N)` crea un vector de N elementos `array([0, 1, ..., N-1])`
- Y seguidamente se usa ese vector para seleccionar las filas.

Eso requiere el uso de una lista intermedia con los N números, que ocupa memoria innecesariamente, y el uso de esa lista para seleccionar elementos es ligeramente más lento (porque es más genérico, al permitirte elegir filas arbitrarias, cosa que en este caso no necesitas pues las quieres contiguas).

Comment: muchisimas gracias, me hacen buena falta unas buenas clases de numPy en profundidad porque tiene mucho más de lo que uno se imagina y encuentra O_o *como anotacion estoy usando python y numpy por primera vez para realizar el tfg de la carrera que como has podido intuir son varios modelos de recomendadores en jueces en línea (webs de ejercicios de programacion). Estuve leyendome durante un mes un libro sobre numpy y pandas pero muchas cosillas se me han ido olvidando que existen, otras no llegue a entenderlas del todo y con el ingles entorpezco más el aprendizaje t_t

Comment: ya como dato final son 3 recomendadores los que estamos implementando y actualmente en la fase de evaluacion en dos de ellos. (Uno bayesiano, uno similar al de K-vecinos más próximos pero mejorado y adaptado y si nos da tiempo pondremos a prueba uno con redes neuronales sencillito que tenemos ya bastante planteado pero no hemos empezado a picar el código)

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado una opción a base de probar opciones de la documentación, la solución correcta es, para una matriz llamada "matriz", y obtener las N primeras filas:

```
matriz[np.arange(N),:]
```